# Why is the movie titled Gothika?

Tags: title, gothika

I have seen the movie [*Gothika*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gothika) (2003). There was no one named **Gothika** in the movie. For me, the movie and the title of the movie didn't sync.

What is the meaning of Gothika?

Comment: Well, after all 2003 *was* the year of the Great Goth Fad, to the point that [Evanescence had a single in the end of year top 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billboard_Year-End_Hot_100_singles_of_2003)...

Comment: Don't know if it's of any relevance but Gothica (English) translates to Gothika in Danish

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [Allocine](http://www.allocine.fr/film/fichefilm-50709/secrets-tournage/), a reference about movies in France,

> Le titre Gothika renvoie clairement à la tradition de la littérature gothique. Né à la fin du 18e siècle en Angleterre, ce style met en scène des personnages prisonniers de lieux isolés et affrontant des phénomènes macabres et mystérieux, voire surnaturels.

Here is my own translation:

> The title *Gothika* clearly refers to the tradition of Gothic literature. Born at the end of the 18th century in England, this style stages characters imprisoned in isolated places and facing macabre and mysterious phenomena, even supernatural.

This fits with the atmosphere and themes of the movie. I couldn't find if this is Allocine's guess, or if it comes from an interview of the director Mathieu Kassovitz (who happens to be French)

Answer (score 20):

Gothika is just a made-up word that you won't find in the movie. You might find different definitions of this word but none of them are verified. However, it seems this word is derived from the word "Gothica", i.e. related to Gothic styles.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0348836/faq#fq0022748) with emphasis of mine,

> **Most likely, gothika is merely an affectatious spelling of gothica** and is similar to other "-ca" words such as "galactica" (things pertaining to the galaxy) or "erotica" (things pertaining to erotic media). Thus, gothika can best be described as "things pertaining to Gothic styles," as in architecture (i.e., the Woodward prison resembles a creepy Gothic castle), art (the Anima Sola), the supernatural, the macabre, and preoccupation with death. **Even the movie's photography, with its focus on blues and blacks, is suggestive of the dark and gloominess associated with Gothic literature.**

Answer (score -3):

Im not sure the reason for the title other than Goth is associated with dark gloomy things and this movie is definitely dark and gloomy. I always figured the director  put that name in there because it was such a popular thing at the time to be Goth that he thought he'd sell more movie tickets to be honest . Now if you watch the scene where Miranda and Chloe have had a therapy session is beginning when they're trying to get Chloe into her room she screams Gothika 2 or 3 times so there you go there's where the Gothica name was used in the movie and squeezed it in . what it means is up to everybody I guess each person can maybe figure out what they think they are theory of Gothica is